# Ruby: how to replace words in my .text madlib with user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a madlib in a .text file and now I need to replace a noun, verb, and adjective with user input. Here's what I have...

**.txt file**---

> "During first snow I was driving down the" [noun] "and was caught by
>   surprise! While driving what I thought was a" [adj] "truck that could
>   plow through anything, I found myself" [verb] "in a 12 inch snow
>   drift. From there it was Man vs Snow! How would I get out? I jumped
>   out and" [adv] "for battle. Me and my ...broom! I lost!"

**.rb file**---

```
file = File.new("myfile.txt", "r")

#start collecting user input-----------------------------------------------------

    #clear display area
    Console_Screen.cls


    #prompt user for input for noun--------------------------------
    print %Q{Type a noun? (Press Enter) \n\n: }

    #force user to press enter to continue
    noun = STDIN.gets

    #remove any extra characters appended to the string
    noun.chomp!
    noun = [noun]

    #clear display area
    Console_Screen.cls

    #prompt user for input for verb-------------------------------
    print %Q{Type a verb. (Press Enter) \n\n: }

    #force player to press enter to continue
    verb = STDIN.gets

    #remove any extra characters appended to the string
    verb.chomp!

    #clear display area
    Console_Screen.cls

    #prompt user for input for adjective---------------------------------
    print %Q{Type an adjective. (Press Enter) \n\n: }

    #force user to press enter to continue
    adj = STDIN.gets

    #remove any extra characters appended to the string
    adj.chomp!

    #clear display area
    Console_Screen.cls

    #prompt user for input for adverb---------------------------------
        print %Q{Type an adverb. (Press Enter) \n\n: }

        #force user to press enter to continue
        adv = STDIN.gets

        #remove any extra characters appended to the string
        adv.chomp!

        #clear display area
    Console_Screen.cls


    #Time to tell the story!----------------------------------------    


puts story

    end
```

Comment: 1) Nothing to do with Ruby on Rails. 2) What specifically is your question? Does your program not work? How specifically?

Comment: i need to know how to make it so that my output is the story but with replaced words from user input.